# Location of touch in UIButton action

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, ibaction, uitouch

I'm trying to get the (x,y) location of where a button is tapped. I've found answers but they don't work for Swift 2.3.
Any suggestions?
That's what I have tried:

```
 @IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: AnyObject, forEvent event: UIEvent) {    
    let buttonView = sender as! UIView;    

    // get any touch on the buttonView
    if let touch = event.touchesForView(buttonView) as? UITouch{
        // print the touch location on the button
        print(touch.locationInView(buttonView))
    }
}
```

Comment: Any code from solutions you've already tried?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Swift 2:**

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(button: UIButton, forEvent event: UIEvent) {
    guard let touch = event.allTouches()?.first else { return }
    let point = touch.locationInView(button)
    print ("point: \(point)")
}
```

**Swift 3:**

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ button: UIButton, forEvent event: UIEvent) {
    guard let touch = event.allTouches?.first else { return }
    let point = touch.location(in: button)
    print ("point: \(point)")
}
```

To create an IBAction with event pick the right option in this popup in your storyboard:

[image]

Comment: @MarcIbrahim You're welcome. In fact the code you posted should work as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
func addGesture() {
let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.buttonTapped(sender:)));
gestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
gestureRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
button.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)  }


func buttonTapped(sender:UIGestureRecognizer) {
    print(sender.location(in: button))

}
```

You can add Gesture recognizer to UIButton and it will work as well

Answer (score -1):

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
        let touch = touches.allObjects[0] as UITouch
        let touchLocation = touch.locationInView(self.view)

    }
```

Hope this will be useful

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but not it's an IBAction from a UIButton not a touchesBegan method.